# Simple Java program for class

Tags: java

I was wondering how do I deal with users entering 1 wife, 1 sack, etc into my program. In order to get the amount of living things, I multiply them all together, but it won't account for the fact that the user entered "1" since it is just multiplying. If a user enters "1" for any of the values, the answer won't be correct.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program2 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int wives;
    int sacks;
    int cats;
    int kits;

    System.out.println("St. Ives Program. Press 'Enter' to continue.");  
    try{
        System.in.read();
    } catch(Exception e){}  

    System.out.println("How many wives does the man have?");
    wives = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many sacks per wife?");
    sacks = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many cats per sack?");
    cats = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many kits per cat?");
    kits = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("As I was going to St. Ives,");

    //This makes it so if a user inputs "1", the correct usage of the word is displayed
    if (wives == 1){
        System.out.println("I met a man with " + wives + " wife,");
    }else{
        System.out.println("I met a man with " + wives + " wives,");
    }

    if (sacks == 1){
        System.out.println("Every wife had " + sacks + " sack,");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Every wife had " + sacks + " sacks,");
    }

    if (cats == 1){
        System.out.println("Every sack had " + cats + " cat,");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Every sack had " + cats + " cats,");
    }

    if (kits == 1){
        System.out.println("Every cat had " + kits + " kit,");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Every cat had " + kits + " kits,");
    }   

    System.out.println("Kits, cats, sacks, and wives,");
    System.out.printf("%d living things were going to St. Ives. %n", (wives * sacks * cats * kits));
    //el fin
    }
}
```

Comment: The line in question is the very last "System.out.printf()"

Comment: You shouldn't ignore the exceptions (`catch(Exception e){}`).

Comment: Just multiplying is not enough. You need to think about your final formula a bit more. Try a few different things (perhaps addition, as well?) till you get a formula which will work for any numbers (including all 1s).

Comment: This is not a Java question, but a basic arithmetic problem.

Comment: what is the correct answer?

Comment: wives = wives, cats = wives * sacks * cats, man = 1. Living things = wives * (1 + sacks * cats) + 1 ?

Comment: more than one wife at the start: 0 wives at the end because they start fighting and divorce him?

Answer (score 0):

As you have to add wifes, cats, kits its basically

```
1 + wives + (wives * sacks * cats) + (wives * sacks * cats * kits)
```

or

```
1 + (wives * (1 + (sacks * cats * (1 + kits)))
```

(`1 +` to account for the man)

Answer (score 0):

Livings things = Number of Men + Number of Wives + Number of Cats + Number of Kits

```
Number of Men = 1
Number of Wives = (Number  of Wives) * (Number of Men) = (Number  of Wives)
Number of Cats = (Number  of Wives) * (Number  of Sacks for each wife) * (Number of Cats in each Sack)
Number of Kits = Number of Cats * (Number of Kits per Cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer brevity

```
   //This makes it so if a user inputs "1", the correct usage of the word is displayed
   System.out.println("I met a man with " + wives + (wives==1?" wife,":" wives,"));
```

Your formula is wrong, you are only showing number of kits, 
you need to add number of cats and number of wives to that.

Is the man also going to St. Ives?